# Binary Reconstruction Algorithm

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to write a simple binary reconstruction algorithm in *matlab*. So far I know this algorithm is used after the opening to *grow back* pieces of the original image that are connected to the opening. I've also found out that it removes small regions that are disjoint from larger objects without distorting the small feature of the large objects.

This is the pseudo code:

```
1. J = I o Z; %open input image with some structre element
2. T = J;
3. J = J  Z(k) % Dilate J with Z(k). this is my first problems. if Z in first line is structure element, then what is Z(k)?
4. J = I AND J % my second problem. how to AND these two on matlab.
5. if J ~= T go to 2.
6. else stop and J is the reconstructed image.
```

Suppose we have this image as input:

[image: input image]

The reconstructed image looks like:

[image: reconstructed image]

With the above mentioned code, so far I've wrote:

```
img = imread ('Input.jpg');
img = im2bw(img, 0.8);
J = bwmorph(img,'open');
T = J;
J = bwmorph(J, 'dilate');
```

My question is how to end this correctly in MATLAB.

My second question is if I'm about to use `imdilate` instead of `bwmorph` what should be my structure element in mentioned example?

Comment: upload your images to web service (http://tinypic.com/) and post a link to the pics.

Comment: please be more specifc at what you are trying do to. please don't send us to read papers - just provide a concise description of what you are trying and why you have trouble doing that.

Comment: I used (http://imgur.com) and still got the error. this is how I did it at first:
![Input Image](http://i.imgur.com/34tXXPC.jpg)

Comment: you got the image now - you can edit your post using the image.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Assume we have [this picture](http://i.imgur.com/cXuBVhP.jpg) and we wanne get [this one](http://i.imgur.com/YzMAT3H.jpg),in which noise is removed, and details preserved. for doing this with morphological operands, one have to do as follow:
[pseudo code](http://i.imgur.com/DxKWRPT.jpg)
what I don't know is how to code the third and the forth lines.

Comment: Can you explain what the operands mean in your context? I took a bried look and there doesn't seem to be a standard definition easily available (on the first 3 pages of google, anyway). Also what is Zk (Z is an SE? What's an SE?) - a neighbourhood-connected image?

Comment: @HughNolan I would guess that SE == "structuring element"

Comment: Ah a structure element, I see. One way to do this would be to convolve your image J with Zk - a 4 or 8 point structure element, it would look like a cross or a block. You dilate function probably does this fine - you could look at `doc bwmorph` to see what methods it uses for its `dilate` function. Hint: it's an 8 point SE. For part 2, you can use a single `T&J` to AND them together, or you can use scalar multiplication - `T.*J` to do the same. However, if you read the pseudocode in the image, you'll see that it is ANDing I and J, not T and J - did you mean to change this?

Comment: @ Hugh Nolan You're right. AND goes for I & J. T should remain unchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments above, you would want to do something like this:

```
img = imread ('Input.jpg');
img = im2bw(img, 0.8);
J = bwmorph(img,'open');
THRESH = 0;
while (1)
    T = J;
    J = bwmorph(J, 'dilate');
    J = img & J;
    if (sum(T(:) - J(:)) <= THRESH)
        break;
    end
end
```

Based on the pseudocode, you can set THRESH = 0 (i.e. T = J), but in real life, you might accept some small amount of difference.

Comment: @ Hugh Nolan Thanks, Thats it. And based on your comment I guess one could also use [this](http://i.imgur.com/Sk2HLxN.jpg) as structure element and write:
  
   J = imopen(img, se);
   T = J;
   While (J ~= T) 
    T = J;
    J = imdilate(J,se);
    J = I & J;
   end